# Insert Record every time when page is refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have this in code Behind : 
When I insert a row in to the database it's insert correct but when i Refresh the page last inserted row is inserted again and again .

```
 protected void ButtonExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string connectionString =cs.getConnection();
            string insertSql = "INSERT INTO profitCategories(name, IdUser) VALUES(@name, @UserId)";

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBoxCategory.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", cui.getCurrentId());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            TextBoxCategory.Text = string.Empty;

        }
```

THIS solved my problem : [New row inserted for each page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984090/new-row-inserted-for-each-page-refresh?lq=1)

Comment: See this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984090/new-row-inserted-for-each-page-refresh Same thing is asked here...

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the method, perform a redirect to the same page, this will clear out the POSTed data.

Something like this:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: this is not working still get replicate of last record if reload the page

Comment: You are correct. I changed my answer. See if that works for you.