# To avoid re-run the code, click on Refresh page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

i have ListView control in aspx page and this control inside ListView control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="addToCart" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' OnCommand="addToCart_Click">Add Cart</asp:LinkButton>
```

and use this code to master page:

```
 <%@ Page  EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ...
```

also, ListView ViewStateMode is Enabled. and this code:

```
protected void addToCart_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //insert product into cart table
    }
```

First, I'll click on addToCart and code is executed. (this OK) But, Code re-runs (insert product into cart table) then when I click on Refresh page!!

Comment: Your Code Insert a record when you refresh your page right...?

Comment: my code has insert value to sql, But, Code re-runs (insert product into cart table) then when I click on Refresh page.

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984090/new-row-inserted-for-each-page-refresh . I think your problem discussed here.

Comment: thx. But when I'm on the second list view page. I want the page to be displayed. I do not want redirect page.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect back to the page from the addToCart_Click callback.

```
Response.Redirect("PageUrl.aspx");
```

You could refer to this pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I do not want Redirect page.

Comment: As far as I know it's the only solution. Did you see the pattern in the wiki? What you're experiencing is an extremely common problem.

Comment: thx. But when I'm on the second list view page. I want the page to be displayed. I do not want redirect page. please help me for Redirect.